# Handling Race Conditions in C#

Tags: c#, race-condition

I'm writing an application with a layered communications interface.
This was done to abstract the communications from the user-interface part of the application and also to make it more scaleable/maintainable.
 
For instance:

[image]

Consider each box in the figure above as a separate class.
The Generic Comms Interface populates string variables describing the transacted data and comms "health," which are in turn copied up to the Application through a series of public function calls.  For example, the Application would make a call to the App-Sub-System:

```
class Application
{
   private void SomeUpdateFunction()
   {
      this.textBox1.AppendText(this.AppSubSystem.GetText());
   }
}

class AppSubSystem
{
   public string GetText()
   {
      return this.GenericCommsInterface.GetText();
   }
}

class GenericCommsInterface
{
   public string GetText()
   {
      string sRetVal = this.sText; // sText is populated by other functions in the class.
      this.sText = null; // Suspected race condition is here.
      return sRetVal;
   }
}
```

`sText` is populated asynchronously by other functions in the class.
I belive a race condition is happening between `string sRetVal = this.sText;` and the following line `this.sText = null;`.
Can someone suggest a way to avoid or prevent this race condition?  Would using `StringBuilder` help, or is there another way that I should be doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably be acquiring a lock any time you want to touch `this.sText` -- in the functions that update it, as well as your `GetText` function.  This would ensure that only one thread at a time is messing with it, as (assuming your thread has the lock) other threads will sit and wait til the current thread is done.

I'd recommend you use a StringBuilder, partly to simplify locking, as locking a string that happened to be interned, or one switched out in the middle of the locked operation (and thus unlocked, from an outsider's perspective) could cause real bad mojo. 
Something like this would help:

```
lock (this.sbText)
{
    sRetVal = this.sbText.ToString();
    this.sbText.Length = 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you could lock on `this`, but that's ugly -- your locks should be inside, as private as possible, in order to avoid weird side effects (like if some other object were trying to acquire a lock on this object -- it couldn't do so while `sbText` was being altered).

Comment: Very bad to 'lock' onto an object not guaranteed to be stable across the thread access -- locks are 'advisory' in that everyone must use/honor them. This is particularly bad because you keep changing the lock object (by setting the variable that contains it to null).

Comment: Thanks for the tips!  I replaced `private string sText` with `private StringBuilder cText` and implemented the locks.  It works great!  The race condition has dissapeared.  Kudos!

Answer (score 1):

This code most certainly won't work in a threaded environment as you aren't protecting sText.  You need to lock everybody that accesses it.

Comment: It'll work -- *sometimes*.  Other times, messages will mysteriously disappear.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string GetText()
{
   lock( someObject )
   {
      string sRetVal = this.sText; // sText is populated by other functions in the class.
      this.sText = null; // Suspected race condition is here.
      return sRetVal;
   }
}
```

in your set

```
lock( someObject )
{
    //...
    this.sText = value;
}
```

Comment: This will *NOT* do it--a new string could be written in after the read but before the null.  The whole operation must be protected, not just the parts.

Comment: interning will bite you in the nether regions.. locking on a string is worse than not locking at all.

Comment: I don't disagree, but I didn't define my lock object at all, let alone define it as string.  I was assuming he could take the gist of the thing and fill in the blanks.